# How to configure g:form for nested resource

Tags: forms, rest, grails

i would like to use the nested resource url mapping stuff, that was introduced in Grails 2.3. I have trouble with getting `<g:form />` working with something like this:

```
"/books"(resources:'book') {
  "/author"(resource:"author")
}
```

In this case i use a single resource for author. If i would like to have a form in `/books/1/author/edit`, which updates the author of the corresponding book.

My question is, how can `<g:form />` can be configured, so that it will use the url `/books/1/author` as the action? According to the docs on [g:form](http://grails.org/doc/2.4.x/ref/Tags/form.html), there is no option to set a resource attribute like it can be done in [g:link](http://grails.org/doc/2.4.x/ref/Tags/link.html). Are there any other possibilities, or is the use of an form within this whole grails REST stuff not a first class citizen? Another thing that let me think it would work this way is the Grails 2.3 REST Improvements proposal [wiki article](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/wiki/Grails-2.3%3A-REST-Improvements#link-generation-enhancements), where these lines of code brought me into this direction:

```
// nested resources
<g:form resource="book/author" bookId="1" id="2" method="DELETE"> -> /books/1/authors/2
<g:form resource="book/author" bookId="1" id="2" method="PUT"> -> /books/1/authors/2 
<g:link resource="book/author" action="edit" bookId="1" id="2"> -> /books/1/authors/edit/1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm running grails 2.4 and this works for me:

```
<g:form resource="author" params="[bookId: 1] action="save">
  <input type="hidden" id="2" />
</g:form>
```